# Translate day of the week from ms:format-date

Tags: xml, date, datetime, xslt

In my xml file, I'm currently returning the date like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(ActivityTime, 'dddd dd MMM yyyy')"></xsl:value-of>
```

I was wondering if there's a way I can translate the day of the week for a given culture. E.g. If the above returned Monday, if I pass in FR_fr, it would return Lundi instead?

I've tried the following, temporarily hard-coding, FR_fr but it didn't work:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ms:format-date(ActivityTime, 'dddd dd MMM yyyy', 'FR_fr')"></xsl:value-of>
```

Comment: `ms:format-date()` is not part of XSLT. You need to consult the specification for the extensions provided by your XSLT processor - I am guessing that would be https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256099%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: What did output? Always show errors or undesired and desired results. Did it return same value as first? Try `fr_FR` for locale (might be case-sensitive). And do you have namespace declared in header: `xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`. Would be helpful to see entire script as placement of this `<xsl:value-of>` matters.